# Count the number of times a value is repeated in a column of excel based on a condition

Tags: excel, count

There is a list of event types listed in column A, and there is large number of events in column C. Every event in column C has a feature that can have a number of states including "PDA" "tab" "device" and blank. Now I am trying to count the number of times each event type happened but only when the associated feature was "PDA" or blank :
[image: data]

Can you help me please?

Many Thanks,

Hamid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`COUNTIFS` wouldn't work here because you can only set a criteria on the very same column (col `A` in your case).

You can try this kind of formula (to get the whole values):

```
SUMPRODUCT((A1:A10=C1:C10)*(OR(B1:B10="PDA",BA:B10=" ")))
```

**[EDIT]**
If you want to get the values for each value, try (in cell `D1` for instance):

```
SUMPRODUCT(($C$1:$C$10=A1)*(OR($B$1:$B$10="PDA",ISEMPTY($B$1:$B$10))))
```

And drag and drop the values till the end

**[EDIT 2]**
Depending on the data formatting, you could try using a **Pivot Table**

Comment: Thanks JMAX. It comes up with #N/A and I guess the problem is that columns A and C are not the same size? Can I perhaps email you the actual data columns in a spreadsheet? I'll be very gateful if you can have a look at it.

Comment: Yes it is. You have to put the same size in the array, even if you don't have data. For instance, if you column A ends at 15 and column C ends at row 20. You have to use the formula with 20 everywhere. I don't think you will have to send me the data by mail. We can have a try here first.

Comment: I tried this, but having just read the help file on SUMPRODUCT I think it counts the number of times the elements of the two columns are equal whereas I need to know how many times F3 appears in column C, then F4, ... After using your code I just have one value of 28 which I guess is the summ of all the frequencies of F3, F4, D3, ...

Comment: perhaps I need to explain a bit more about what I am trying to do :) There is a list of event types listed in column A, and there is large number of event in column C. Every event in column C had a feature that can have a number of states including "PDA" "tab" "device" and blank. Now I am trying to count the number of times each event type happened but only when that feature was "PDA" or blank

Comment: If you want to count both "PDA" and empty cells, my second formula will work. If not, this will be a little tricky. Eventually, you could use a Pivot Table. Eventually, please edit your question to be clearer.

Comment: apologies for the vagueness of the question. I tried the second formula but it seems to be ignoring the condition on the elements of B column because when I just use COUNTIF to count the number of occurences of A elements in C column it gives me the same number, regardless of the condition of the feature in B column

Comment: I probably misunderstood your data. Column A are only used as reference? Hence, I've made some changes to my second formula. You may have an issue with the "blank" cells.

Comment: yes column A is reference. apologies if I explained not so well. Many thanks for the help. problem solved now